# Can't send a message to a distant machine

Tags: c#, .net, udp, chat

I'm trying to make an UDP client and UDP server to send messages through Internet between two distant computers.

The server code is:

```
public class Server {

    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        var t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Listen));
        t.Start();
    }

    private static void Listen() {
        UdpClient server = new UdpClient(5035);

        while(true) {
            IPEndPoint client = null;
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a message...");

            // listening
            byte[] data = server.Receive(ref client);
            Console.WriteLine("Message received from {0}:{1}.", client.Address, client.Port);

            string message = Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
            Console.WriteLine("-> {0}\n", message);
        }
    }
}
```

And the client code is:

```
public class Client {

    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        while(true) {
            Console.Write("\nEnter a message : ");
            string message = Console.ReadLine();

            // serialization
            byte[] msg = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(message);

            // sending
            UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient();
            udpClient.Send(msg, msg.Length, "127.0.0.1", 5035);
            udpClient.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

If I run the Server and the Client on the same network or the two on the same computer all works perfectly. The problem appears when the Client and the Server are on two **distant networks**.

To try this, I sent the Client code to a friend and I gave him my Internet Box IP Address, my box receives all the messages but not me, the only way to make it works, it's to add an **internal NAT box rule** :
I say to my box to redirect all messages on the port 5035, to my computer on the same port and now **it works**.

But I **don't want to use this way**. Is there any solutions to send UDP messages between two distant machines on two distant networks, through Internet without add an internal NAT box rule ? (maybe using a subnet mask ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the NAT rule on the router.

Consumer routers by default block all incoming traffic, acting like a basic firewall.
Installing the NAT rule opens the port on the router and grant access on that port over the internet.

It's considered good practice to secure remote locations. 
You'll need to take firewalls into account when developing networked applications.
The internet is an "evil" environment, open networks without any security are a hackers dream.